# Hide iFrame while section not visible/active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Im trying on a bootstrapwebsite, make an iframe (substitute with another / better (?) option if possible) only loads/displayed when the part/section of the page is active.
My page is one long page with sections (single page index.html) where each section includes an iframe that loads an entire website.

CSS for my sections:

```
section {
padding-top: 50px; / * Margin menubar * /
height: 100vh; / * 100% of the visible field * /

}
```

The problem I have is that now all iframes loads simultaneously and steals focus, and the page jumps up and down while it is loading.
And when everything is finished loading you have come to the center or between sections.
It looks really bad and it consumes unnecessary bandwidth.

Section 0 - rss (page should always start here)
Section 1 - Router
Section 2 - work mail1
Section 3 - work mail2
Section 4 - NAS
Section 5 - Synology DiskStation
Section 6 - Plex

```
<! - Plex section ->
<Section id = "plex">
<Iframe style = "position: absolute; top: -9999em; visibility: hidden;" onload = "this.style.position = 'static'; this.style.visibility = 'visible'; ' src = "http://plex.tv/web/app" href = "http://plex.tv/web/app" width = "100%" height = "100%"> </ iframe>
</ Section>
<! - End Plex section ->
```

html5, javascript, jQuery, ajax, anything is welcome (exept flash), im on a dead end.

---

i want the iframe to load a local blank page until it´s visible,   when i click a navbar link, the page scrolls down to an achorpoint (section) then i want that sections iframe to load.and if i scroll to another section i want the first iframe to unload or load the blank page and the new sections iframe to load it´s content.. all iframes have different pages to load and is on different pages anchor points of the page.

[link to example jfiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/9x0m004L
```

Comment: you can use jQuery `scroll` + `ajax`. OR just try this link https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what exactly you want to do?
If you want your sections to be loaded continuously from the top to bottom without scrolling:

```
var urls = ["google.com","google.com","google.com","google.com"];
$(document).on("iframeLoad", function(){
    if(urls.length > 0) {
        var newDiv = $('<div class="divWrap"/></div>').appendTo(document.body);
        $("<div>title</div>").appendTo(newDiv);
        var newIframe = $('<iframe src="'+urls.shift()+'"></iframe>').appendTo(newDiv);
        newIframe.load(function(){
            $(document).trigger("iframeLoad");
        });
    }
});
$(document).trigger("iframeLoad");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vp96xx3z/